# Is this the correct SQL syntax to import a csv file to MS Access?

Tags: c++, sql, ms-access, import, ado

I am trying to load content of a local file and upload it to MS Access database using ADO in C++.

I've wrote following SQL syntax:

```
commandline = "SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',''HDR=NO;Database=C:\\temp\\data.csv;')";
```

But the code end up with error: `Syntax error in FROM clause`

I am quite confused by the strange syntax in MS Access, so I'm not sure what am I wrong.

Can anyone help me out of this? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems nobody is interested. Fortunately, I've resolved it myself with following code:

```
commandline = "SELECT * INTO TABLE FROM [Text;HDR=YES;DATABASE=C:\\temp\\].[data.csv]";
```